# Адаптивное меню не правильно работает

Tags: html, css

Делаю адаптивное меню. Делаю его через `input` и `label`.

Все работает корректно, пока не подключаю второй, третий и т.д. пункты. 
Тогда при нажатии на любую кнопку, открывается только последняя.

Искала ошибку, написано все вроде верно. Помогите, пожалуйста, советом, если знаете как исправить ситуацию.

```css
nav{
    background: #ffdead;
  }
  .menu *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .menu ul,
  .menu ol{
    list-style: none;
  }
  .menu > ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .menu ul li a{
    display: block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.6), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    padding: 10px 31px 10px 26px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #151515;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 0 #000;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0.7;
    white-space:nowrap;
  }
  .menu li a:hover{
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px -5px black;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /*sub menu*/
  .menu li ul{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
  }

  .menu li ul a{
    white-space:normal;
    max-width: 145px;
  }
  .menu li < ul li{
    border: 1px solid #D2691E;
  }
.menu [type='checkbox'],
.menu label.toggleSubmenu{
display: none;
}
.menu label.toggleMenu{
display: none;
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.6), rgba(0,0,0,0));
padding: 15px 40px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 15px;
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
.menu label.toggleMenu .fa{
position: absolute;
top: 17px;
left: 14px;
font-size: 18px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px){
.menu li:hover > ul{
display: block;
opacity: 1;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
body{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu ul li a{
  padding: 15px 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: block;
} 


.menu label.toggleMenu{
  display: block;
}
.menu ul{
  display: none;
}
.menu li > ul li ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
}
input.toggleMenu:checked + label.toggleMenu{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
  color: #FFDEAD;
}
input.toggleMenu:checked ~ ul,
input.toggleSubmenu:checked ~ ul{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.menu label.toggleSubmenu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.menu li ul a{
white-space:normal;
max-width: 100%;
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9), rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
color: #FFF5EE;
  }
input.toggleSubmenu:checked ~ a{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
  color: #FFDEAD;
}
.menu label.toggleSubmenu .fa::before{
  content: "\f0d7";
  color: #454547;
}
.menu label.toggleSubmenu .fa{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 30px;
}

.menu input.toggleSubmenu:checked ~ label.toggleSubmenu .fa::before{
  content: "\f0d8";
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="menu" class="toggleMenu">
    <label for="menu" class="toggleMenu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Menu</label>
  <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="sub_m1" class="toggleSubmenu">
          <a href="#">мода</a>
        <label for="sub_m1" class="toggleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label> 
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">образ</a></li>  
              <li><a href="#">тренды</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">антитренды</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="sub_m2" class="toggleSubmenu">
        <a href="#">красота</a>
        <label for="sub_m2" class="toggleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">макияж</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">прическа</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">тело</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">лайфхаки</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="a-1" href="#">здоровье</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">лекарства</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">худеем вместе</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">диеты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">упражнения</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">женское здоровье</a></li>
           </ul>
      </li>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте `.menu ul li { position: relative; }`:

```css
nav{
    background: #ffdead;
  }
.menu *{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu ul,
.menu ol{
  list-style: none;
}
.menu > ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.menu ul li a{
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.6), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  padding: 10px 31px 10px 26px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #151515;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 0 #000;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0.7;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.menu li a:hover{
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px -5px black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}
/*sub menu*/
.menu li ul{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu li ul a{
  white-space:normal;
  max-width: 145px;
}
.menu li < ul li{
  border: 1px solid #D2691E;
}
.menu [type='checkbox'],
.menu label.toggleSubmenu{
  display: none;
}
.menu label.toggleMenu{
  display: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.6), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  padding: 15px 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 15px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
.menu label.toggleMenu .fa{
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 14px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px){
  .menu li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
  body{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .menu ul li a{
    padding: 15px 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0 15px;
  }
  .menu ul li {
    display: block;
  } 


  .menu label.toggleMenu{
    display: block;
  }
  .menu ul{
    display: none;
  }
  .menu li > ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  input.toggleMenu:checked + label.toggleMenu{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
    color: #FFDEAD;
  }
  input.toggleMenu:checked ~ ul,
  input.toggleSubmenu:checked ~ ul{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu label.toggleSubmenu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu li ul a{
    white-space:normal;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9), rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    color: #FFF5EE;
  }
  input.toggleSubmenu:checked ~ a{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
    color: #FFDEAD;
  }
  .menu label.toggleSubmenu .fa::before{
    content: "\f0d7";
    color: #454547;
  }
  .menu label.toggleSubmenu .fa{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;
  }

  .menu input.toggleSubmenu:checked ~ label.toggleSubmenu .fa::before{
    content: "\f0d8";
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="menu" class="toggleMenu">  
  <label for="menu" class="toggleMenu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Menu</label>
  
  <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="sub_m1" class="toggleSubmenu">
          <a href="#">мода</a>
        <label for="sub_m1" class="toggleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label> 
        
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">образ</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#">тренды</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">антитренды</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="sub_m2" class="toggleSubmenu">
        <a href="#">красота</a>
        <label for="sub_m2" class="toggleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">макияж</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">прическа</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">тело</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">лайфхаки</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="a-1" href="#">здоровье</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">лекарства</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">худеем вместе</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">диеты</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">упражнения</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">женское здоровье</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Блоки с `position:absolute` позиционируются относительно ближайшего родителя с `position:relative`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все заработало!

Comment: @HamSter У Юлии к сожалению ещё нет прав плюсовать хорошие ответы, ну тогда это я сделаю